# How to draw the surface of many 3D points with Three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, triangulation, concave

I'm working with Three.js. I have a collection of 3D points (x, y, z).
How to draw the surface of it.

It may be a question of concave hull or alpha shape in 3D. I have found ways in 2D points.

Another way is delaunay triangulation?

Who can help me. With a demo best. Thanks!

I have used the THREE.ConvexGeometry, its the convex hull,not ideal.

Comment: I am not sure what you're after but this extra contains a triangulate function: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/ShapeUtils.js